# How to properly configure Netbeans to build openCMS core?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ant, opencms

I'm trying to set up a development environment to build openCMS 10.5 with Netbeans 8.2 under Linux(Linux Mint 32-Bit, but I would be flexible there).

Now I'm getting as far as cloning the openCMS core from git. But I have trouble with creating the Netbeans project(s) so the openCMS core can be build properly.

What I need to know is:
How many projects do I need to create in Netbeans? There are several src-folders, does it need to be one project for each folder?

What kind of project(s) do I need to create? 
There are several types of project like Java Application or Enterprise Application,...

There is an Ant-build-script in the git-clone. Can I use this to create the Netbeans project(s)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need an IDE to build opencms. Just invoke gradle from the command line:

```
gradle bindist
```

If you want to use NetBeans, you don't need to create any project. NetBeans provides support for gradle projects via plugins. Install the "Gradle JavaEE Support" and "Gradle Support" plugins, and open the already cloned directory:

[image: opencms in netbeans: screenshot]

Admittedly, the current gradle project description doesn't make it easy to work with the code (every module have the same set of sources, rendering the project view quite cumbersome), but you can get used to it.